# JUnit - Trying to optimize initializations in @Before

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4

In my IT test class I have `@Before` annotation that initialize some testUtil classes that I use, e.g:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

@Autowired
private ServiceC serviceC;

protected TestUtilA testUtil;
protected TestUtilB testUtil2;

@Before
protected void runBeforeTest() {
   testUtil = new TestUtilA(serviceA, serviceB);
   testUtil2 = new TestUtilB(serviceC); 
}
```

The problem is that it initialize the tests utils before each test (but basicly I need to do it only once).
If I wrap the initialization part in `runBeforeTest()` with `if (testUtil == null)` than tests will throw NPE on those testUtils.

How can I init those utils only once for all tests in class?

Comment: Ehrm... Testing `!- null` will ofcourse lead to `NullPointers`... Then your util will never be assigned... Use `if (testUtil == null) { create stuff }` instead.

Comment: how have you annotated your test class?

Comment: @M.Deinum - it was a typo, fixed it. thanks

Comment: @kuhajeyan - @RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Comment: then I am not sure your bean instantances would be injected correctly. you need to have something like this setup for your test class to find beans

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ApplicationConfig.class})

Comment: btw SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is specialized class of BlockJUnit4ClassRunner http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to achieve the goal you want.

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html):

> **The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be**
>   **executed after dependency injection is done to perform any**
>   **initialization**. This method MUST be invoked before the class is put
>   into service. This annotation MUST be supported on all classes that
>   support dependency injection. The method annotated with PostConstruct
>   MUST be invoked even if the class does not request any resources to be
>   injected. Only one method can be annotated with this annotation.

And the code will be like:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

@Autowired
private ServiceC serviceC;

protected TestUtilA testUtil;
protected TestUtilB testUtil2;

@PostConstruct
public void runOnlyOnce() {
   testUtil = new TestUtilA(serviceA, serviceB);
   testUtil2 = new TestUtilB(serviceC); 
}

@Before
protected void runBeforeTest() {
   // Do something before each test   
}
```

Comment: Try replace `@PostConstruct ` to `@BeforeClass` and change the class to `public static void`.

Answer (score 0):

Following setup should work,

> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ApplicationConfig.class})
public class MyTest {

@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Autowired
private ServiceB serviceB;

@Autowired
private ServiceC serviceC;

protected TestUtilA testUtil;
protected TestUtilB testUtil2;

@Before
protected void runBeforeTest() {
   testUtil = new TestUtilA(serviceA, serviceB);
   testUtil2 = new TestUtilB(serviceC); 
}


}
```